# I can't install Kubuntu 22.04 while Secure Boot is On

Tags: dual-boot, secure-boot

I installed **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop** while Secure Boot is enabled, and so far, it works.

Now, I'm trying to install **Kubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop** on my Hyper-V to see if it will work while Secure Boot is enabled but **Kubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop** requires disabling Secure Boot.

BIOS: **UEFI Insyde Corp. V1.33** ||
SM BIOS **Version: 3.0** ||
BIOS Mode: **UEFI**

Comment: Unless you are dual booting Windows 11 secure boot should be off.

Comment: I currently have Win11/Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop Dual Boot on my System while Secure Boot is Enabled, is Kubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop different from the Ubuntu I installed?

Comment: Installer is the same. And I (accidentally) installed Kubuntu to my Dell with Secure boot on. I normally turn it off. But I did have to have Windows bitlocker off & fast start up in Windows off. Because Dell only has NVMe drive, it also installed with RAID on, where normally you have to change to AHCI. It used Kubuntu used Intel VMD driver to access NVMe drive.

Comment: Ubuntu uses Ubiquiti as an installer, you're able to install Kubuntu (which version?) while RAID is enabled?

Comment: @David Why not disable it if I am dual booting Windows??